# How to display all elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I added subproject(collection) to project (collection).
I put one of the elements in props. But It can't be defined.
I also would like to loop and display all elements? How Should I do?

The error =>
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'RFv6bJMG2dmiBqWNZX8O' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

> 23 |     
> | ^  24 | {project.answers.map(answer => {
> 25 |   return (
> 26 |     {answer.id}

https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app/blob/master/src/Components/projects/ProjectDetails.js

```
const ProjectDetails = (props) => {
    const { project } = props;
    
    if (project) {
        return (
            <div className="container section project-details">
                <div className="card z-depth-0">
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <span className="card-title">{ project.title }</span>
                        <p>{ project.content }</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-action gret lighten-4 grey-text">
                        <div>Posted by {project.userName}</div>
                        <div>2nd, September, 2am</div>
                    </div>
<-- I would to display all data of sub projects--> 
                <div>{project.subproject['RFv6bJMG2dmiBqWNZX8O'].contents}</div>

            {project.answers && project.answers.map(answer => {
              return (
                <div>{answer.id}
                {answer.content}
                </div>
              )
                </div>
            </div>
)}
```

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const projects = state.firestore.data.projects;
    const project = projects ? projects[id] : null;
    const subprojects = project ? project.subprojects : "unloaded";
   
    console.log("sub ="+JSON.stringify(subprojects));
    return {
        project: project
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect(props => [
        {collection: 'projects'},
        {
        collection: 'projects',
        doc:props.match.params.id,
        subcollections :[{collection:'subprojects'}]  }
    ]
))(ProjectDetails);
```

Comment: Is `'RFv6bJMG2dmiBqWNZX8O'` a property key?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
<div>answers = {project.subproject?.['RFv6bJMG2dmiBqWNZX8O']?.contents}</div>
```

Comment: Please try to expand a little on your solution, don't just post "try this..."

Comment: @kuhnroyal thank you, I will improve in the next answers